# Variables naming style

Tags: variables, language-agnostic, naming-conventions

What do you prefer to use and what is the best practice - to make long but very meaningful names or to make shorter ones?

For example, if you are writing a class House, will be

```
int numberOfRooms;
```

or

```
int nRooms;
```

Sure, long names are better for understandig when you read foreign code or give yours to somebody, but they make code longer -> more complicated to read. So I messed up with it. :)

Comment: I've never seen variables named like `nRooms`. `numRooms` at the shortest, but I prefer meaningful names.

Comment: There's always a balance to be sought, but I prefer to err on the side of readability for the next programmer working on my code. In your example, I'd go with `roomCount`.

Comment: A lot of the times I like using underscores... num_rooms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most important things is understanding code.

It's better to name the variable numberOfRooms or numOfRooms than nRooms - nRooms could mean something else and numOfRooms is just 4 characters longer - so, I think, it worths to name it a little longer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the house naming style for wherever you are working.  Other colleagues will be maintaining your code in the future and it is best to make it easy for them.
2. If you are working for yourself then use the standard naming style for the language you are using.  Delphi, Java, C# and others all have standard styles.
3. If you are working on a collaborative project then follow the house naming style for that project.
4. As Miroslav says, longer names are generally better, within reason.